# how to extract data JSON from zeppelin sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'd like to see data with JSON type using a query.

The test_tbl table details are here and tags column contains data as JSON type below

```
%sql
desc stg.test_tbl
col_name | data_type | comment
id       |  string   |
title    |  string   |
tags     |  string   |
```

Record from tag column: `{"name":[{"family": null, "first": "nelson"}, {"pos_code":{"house":"tlv", "id":"A12YR"}}]}`

I queried as below and an error that cannot extract value from tags column.

- Query

```
select *, tag.*
from stg.test_tbl as t
lateral view explode(t.tags.name) name as name
lateral view explode(name.pos_code) pos_code as pos_code
```

- Error

```
Can't extract value from tags#3423: need struct type but got string; line 3 pos 21
set zeppelin.spark.sql.stacktrace = true to see full stacktrace
```

should I use string in where statement?

Comment: the data type is string, not struct. The json data is treated as string, so you cannot use struct.

Comment: @Lamanus You're right, I didnt know the column type is in String, not array as json type. So, I queried data in String type using get_json_object https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered myself. I could use `get_json_object` in string type in  JSON.

In case it's in array as shown below

```
{"name":[{"family": null, "first": "nelson"}, {"pos_code":{"house":"tlv", "id":"A12YR"}}]}
```

Then I could query using the key

```
select * from stg.test_tbl as t
where t.pos_code[0].house = "tlv"
```